# Data not saving across scenes

Tags: unity, c#

I've been trying to save a player's score with PlayerPrefs, however every time i change scenes, the game simply stops tracking the score and doesn't even add score when told to, anyone has any idea of what i'm doing wrong?

Game Controller code:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int totalScore;
    public Text scoreText;
    public GameObject gameOver;
    public GameObject winScreen;

    public static GameController instance;

    void Start()
    {
        instance = this;
        totalScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("points");
    }


    public void UpdateScoreText()
    {
        scoreText.text = totalScore.ToString();
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("points", totalScore);
    }
```

Apple's code(What i use to add score):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Apple : MonoBehaviour
{

    private SpriteRenderer sr;
    private CircleCollider2D circle;
    public int Score;
    public GameObject collected;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        circle = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    { 
        if(collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            sr.enabled = false;
            circle.enabled = false;
            collected.SetActive(true);

            GameController.instance.totalScore += Score;
            GameController.instance.UpdateScoreText();
            
            Destroy(gameObject, 0.25f);   
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GameController.UpdateScoreText () (at Assets/Scripts/GameController.cs:29)
Apple.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D collider) (at Assets/Scripts/Apple.cs:37)
```

Comment: i don't know, it's very confusing to me and i can't find which one of those cases could be mine

Comment: It looks like you have not assigned a text field to the `scoreText` member on the `GameController`, or the one you had was in an old scene and was destroyed when changing scenes, without being replaced.